# cabal sandbox uses system level packages

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

I am trying to run a [haskelldb-demo](https://github.com/chrisdone/haskelldb-demo)

```
cabal sandbox init && cabal install --only-dependencies
```

It needs `HDBC-postgresql-2.2.3.1` which needs base package version as `base>=3 && <4.5`. My system has `base` pkg versioned 4.7+.

I am using cabal sandbox but cabal install still refers to the base (v4.7.0.2)package from the global repository and rejects all versions of HDBC-postgresql

```
rejecting: HDBC-postgresql-2.2.3.1 (conflict: base==4.7.0.2/installed-bfd...,
HDBC-postgresql => base>=3 && <4.5)
```

why does cabal refer to the system level packages, inspite me making a sandbox?

Answer (score 3):

Cabal always use the global package database. Sandboxing only means you don't use the user package database. Presumably it's to make sure you have the base packages and ghc available.

If you have a mismatch on base that means the package you try to install is not compatible with your version of GHC. I would avoid installing different versions of base.

Related questions (without clear answers):

[How to get cabal to ignore the global package DB when using a sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21587200/how-to-get-cabal-to-ignore-the-global-package-db-when-using-a-sandbox)

[cabal sandbox v. global package db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30685248/cabal-sandbox-v-global-package-db)

Comment: It's also possible that the package would actually build fine against a newer version of base if only it didn't have a `base < 4.5` constraint. OP can try adding `--allow-newer=base`.